# Run a for loop with two or more variables without using nested loops

Tags: r, for-loop

I would like to run a for loop with multiple variables which run simultaneously and are not nested.

My code is as follows

```
for (i, j in c(1,2,3), c("a","b","c")){
print(i)
print(j)
}
```

I would like this to print out

```
1
a
2
b
3
c
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

We can loop through the sequence of the vectors

```
for(i in seq_along(x1)) {
        print(x1[i])
        print(y1[i])
  }
```

It is similar to the option of looping using `range` in `python`

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for i in range(len(x)):
    print(x[i])
    print(y[i])
```

#### data

```
x1 <- 1:3
y1 <- letters[1:3]
```

Comment: Thank you! I like how it scales to even more variables

e.g 
    for(i in seq_along(x1)) {print(x1[i]); print(y1[i]); print(z1) }
    x1 <- 1:3
    y1 <- letters[1:3]
    z1 <- c("s","t","u")

Answer (score 0):

Try `mapply`:

```
 mapply(function(x, y) {print(x); print(y)}, x = 1:3, y = letters[1:3])
```

`Map` does something similar as well.